# Having issues with images resizing responsively

Tags: html, css

Heres my CSS that I have for my img syntax.  However, it should responsively resize while the browser resize.  This works in Chrome, but IE & FIREFOX for some reason aren't working - is there a reason why?  I am using the latest of all.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: If the IMG's container is not changing size, neither will the image. There is not enough information to determine this based on what's in your question.

Comment: I've never seen or used that IE8 hack before and my images have always worked fine responsively.

Comment: <img src="images/outdoorsecuritycamera.png" alt="Outdoor Camera" align="left">
            <img src="images/Vanguard-700web-page-logo.png" alt="Vanguard 700">

Comment: Those are my img containers.. So...

Comment: Width should not have `\9` that is not valid CSS

Comment: I took the \9 out (as that was already there with the template) however, it still isn't responding but there template is? I haven't really changed anything in the CSS.  Kind of Weird.

Comment: http://www.kolbree.com/rugged/ if someone wants to "test" it in their browser?

Answer (score 1):

The img max-width: 100% is a good technique for responsive images, but it needs to work together with the image container - element that holds the image / wraps it - for you to see the responsiveness of it in action.

Try this and you should get it working cross browsers:

```
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img src="http://www.thoughtfeast.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Big-Data-2-1024x522.jpg" >
</div>
```

So your image is wrapped with a div. And the CSS would be:

```
.imgHolder{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px dashed red;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.imgHolder img {
       max-width: 100% 
}
```

You can check the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/domkoscielak/pen/KmJGD)